# How old is elementary OS?

Tags: elementary-project

With GNOME celebrating its 18th birthday yesterday, I was wondering how old is elementary project actually? When was Jupiter released? The only info I could find is March 2011 (from Wikipedia), but that's not really specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### elementary: 6 years

#### elementary OS: 4 and a half years

> We released Jupiter on March 31st, 2011. But, elementary icons was registered on Launchpad as far back as June 6th, 2009. So we’ve been around in one form or another for quite a while :)

[Source](http://blog.elementary.io/post/126786393856/how-old-is-elementarys-project-on-which-date-was?utm_medium=email&utm_source=html&utm_campaign=ask_answer)